# Javascript - Cannot check whether a number in array

Tags: javascript, arrays, digits

[image]

This is a terrible situation.

I want to check whether a number is in given array of numbers.
But it returns mysterious result.

Here is my captured console image.

I also check the type of a number and elements in array.
Blue one has number type elements, and red one has string type elements.
As for a single number, blue number is number type and black number is string type. 
But the type does not affect anything to the result.

After checking all results, I figured out numbers above 10, double digits, make problems.
1~10 numbers do not make strange situation.

What is the problem? How can I fix this?

---

Here is my code.
This is a part of long code, so I adjust this a little bit to understand seperately.

```
object = {'2': obj,'3': obj,'10': obj,'11': obj,...}

var array = Object.keys(object);
var newArray = array.map(function(x) {
   return parseInt(x, 10)
});
var newNumber = parseInt(number, 10) // number is from above code, just a number.

console.log(newArray);
console.log(newNumber);
console.log(newNumber in newArray);

console.log(array);
console.log(number.toString());
console.log(number.toString() in array);
    `
```

Comment: can't see your code, so who knows what you're doing wrong

Comment: Sorry. I added my code. It's a part of long code so I have a difficult to explain it. If any additional information needed, please let me know that.

Comment: You can't use `in` to check for values in an array, you use `indexOf` for that

Comment: in other words `array.indexOf(number);`

Comment: @adeneo Wow!!! It works!! Thanks a lot. I spent so much time to fix this. You save me..

Answer (score 0):

You can try `Array.indexOf`

```
var array = [2,3,10,11,12,13,14,18,20,21,25];
var myObject = {'2': obj,'3': obj,'10': obj,'11': obj}

for (let key in myObject){
    if (array.indexOf(parseInt(key)) == -1){ //If the value is not found
        //Element not found
    }
    else{
        //Element found 
    }
}
```

More info about `Array.indexOf` can be found [here](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_indexof_array.asp).

Answer (score 0):

To check whether element exists in the array (true/false), you need to check either `newArray.indexOf(newNumber) !== -1` or `newArray.indexOf(newNumber) > -1` as below.

Also, in your above code of `array.map(function(x) { return parseInt(x, 10) }`, you didn't close the bracket opened by `array.map(`

Working code:

```js
var obj = {};
var object = {'2': obj, '3': obj, '10': obj, '11': obj};

var array = Object.keys(object)
var newArray = array.map(function(x) {
   return parseInt(x, 10)
});
   
var number = 10;
var newNumber = parseInt(number, 10); // number is from above code, just a number.

console.log(newArray);
console.log(newNumber);
console.log(newArray.indexOf(newNumber));
console.log(newArray.indexOf(newNumber) !== -1); // To get true or false you need either this or the below one
console.log(newArray.indexOf(newNumber) > -1);
```